# Android Recycler View Drag to Reorder Not Correctly Updating Recyler View

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an application that has a recycler view filled with live-data items that needs to be able to reorder these items. I've added a handle to each item for it to be dragged by and implemented a basic reorder logic.The problem I'm running into is that when I drag an item the behavior is very unusual. It's difficult to describe so I've added a video here https://streamable.com/joe50r

I'll add the code below, but here is a [link to the branch on my gitlab.](https://gitlab.com/johandley/munchkinland/-/tree/add-rv-drag-to-reorder)

Here's the fragment it's contained in

```
class PlayerListFragment : Fragment(), OnStartDragListener {
private val viewModel: PlayerListFragmentViewModel by viewModel()
private val adapter = PlayerListRecyclerViewAdapter(this )
private val callback: ItemTouchHelper.Callback = ItemReorderCallback(adapter)
private val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(callback)
private val DEFAULT_ACTION_BAR = R.layout.player_list_fragment_custom_action_bar

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setActionBar(DEFAULT_ACTION_BAR)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player_list, container, false)
    }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        observePlayers()
        initializeAddPlayerFabOnClick()
        setRecyclerViewAdapter()
    }
    
    private fun initializeAddPlayerFabOnClick() {
        val addPlayerFab = view?.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.add_player_fab)
        addPlayerFab?.setOnClickListener {
            launchNewPlayerDialog()
        }
    }
    
    private fun setActionBar(actionBarId: Int) {
        val activity = requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity
        val supportActionBar = activity.supportActionBar
        supportActionBar?.displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        supportActionBar?.setCustomView(actionBarId)
        setDefaultActionBarListeners()
    }
    
    private fun setRecyclerViewAdapterItemTouchHelper() {
        val playersRecyclerView =
            requireView().findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.players_recyclerview)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(playersRecyclerView)
    }
    
    private fun setRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        val playersRecyclerView =
            requireView().findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.players_recyclerview)
        playersRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        playersRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        setRecyclerViewAdapterItemTouchHelper()
    }
    
    private fun setDefaultActionBarListeners() {
        val activity = requireActivity() as MainActivity
        val supportActionBar = activity.supportActionBar
        supportActionBar?.customView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.edit_button)?.setOnClickListener {
            showDragHandles()
        }
    }
    
    private fun launchNewPlayerDialog() {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        val builderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_player_dialog, null)
        AddPlayerAlertDialogUtilities.initializeAddPlayerDialogButtons(builder, requireContext())
        builder.setView(builderView)
        val dialog = builder.show()
        AddPlayerAlertDialogUtilities.initializeAutoCompleteTextViews(dialog, resources, requireContext())
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener {
            if (!AddPlayerAlertDialogUtilities.hasErrors(dialog)) {
                createPlayer(dialog)
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private fun createPlayer(dialog: AlertDialog) {
        val player = Player(
            0,
            AddPlayerAlertDialogUtilities.getName(dialog),
            AddPlayerAlertDialogUtilities.getSex(dialog),
            AddPlayerAlertDialogUtilities.getRace(dialog),
            AddPlayerAlertDialogUtilities.getClass(dialog),
            0,
            0
        )
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            viewModel.addPlayer(player)
        }
    }
    
    override fun onStartDrag(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) {
        viewHolder?.let {
            itemTouchHelper.startDrag(it)
        }
    }
    
    private fun observePlayers() {
        viewModel.getAllPlayers().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter.setPlayers(it)
        }
    }
    
    private fun showDragHandles() {
        val recyclerView = requireView().findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.players_recyclerview)
        recyclerView.children.forEach {
            it.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.drag_handle).visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the recycler view adapter.

```
class PlayerListRecyclerViewAdapter(private val onStartDragListener: OnStartDragListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayerListRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(),
    ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
    private var players: List<Player> = ArrayList()
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    var tracker: SelectionTracker<Long>? = null

    init {
        setHasStableIds(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.player_list_recyclerview_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view, onStartDragListener)
    }

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(players[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return players.size
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setPlayers(newDataSet: List<Player>) {
        this.players = newDataSet
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int): Boolean {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (i in fromPosition until toPosition) {
                Collections.swap(players, i, i + 1)
            }
        } else {
            for (i in fromPosition downTo toPosition + 1) {
                Collections.swap(players, i, i - 1)
            }
        }
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
        return true
    }


    override fun onItemDismiss(position: Int) {

    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View, private val onStartDragListener: OnStartDragListener? = null) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun getItemDetails(): ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> =
            object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
                override fun getPosition(): Int = adapterPosition
                override fun getSelectionKey(): Long = itemId
            }

        fun bindItems(player: Player) {
            itemView.tag = player.id
            val sexImageView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.sex_imageview)
            val playerNameTextview = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.player_name_textview)
            val raceAndClassTextview = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.race_and_class_textview)

            val raceAndClassText = "${player.race} ${player.clazz}"
            playerNameTextview.text = player.name
            raceAndClassTextview.text = raceAndClassText

            if (player.sex == "Male") {
                sexImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.male_recycler_view_item_selector)
            } else {
                sexImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.female_recycler_view_item_selector)
            }

            setOnClickListener()
            setOnTouchListener()
        }

        private fun setOnClickListener() {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val parentActivity = itemView.context as MainActivity
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putInt("playerId", itemView.tag as Int)
                parentActivity.inflateFragment(PlayerFragment(), bundle, "PLAYER_FRAGMENT")
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        private fun setOnTouchListener() {
            val dragHandle = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.drag_handle)
            dragHandle.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    onStartDragListener?.onStartDrag(this)
                }
                false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Callback Helper

```
class ItemReorderCallback(private val adapter: ItemTouchHelperAdapter) : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

    override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun getMovementFlags(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Int {
        val dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0)
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        adapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

I've actually tried this exact implementation in a separate project and it's working. The only difference I've noticed between them is that for some reason in the project that's working it does not call onBindViewHolder after moving an item, but in the broken project it does. I suspect this could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is painful, because it results because of one line of code.

I had to change this

setHasStableIds(true)

to this

setHasStableIds(false)

in my selection tracker. The internal RecyclerView code checks that flag when scrapping views and I'm not sure why, but I'm sure it's perfectly intended, it causes the view scrapping to be processed differently.